# How to pass a premade list of functions to cast

Tags: r, reshape2

`cast`, from the `reshape2` package, can handle a bunch of functions if passed directly in the call. For example:

```
library(reshape2)

d <- data.frame(variable="variable",value=rnorm(100))
cast(d, variable ~ ., c(mean,sd,max,min))
```

But, this doesn't work if you try to build the list of functions before hand. For example:

```
summary.fun <- c(mean,sd,max,min)
cast(d, variable ~., summary.fun)
```

I looked at the code for cast that deals with this particular behaviour and, to be honest, I have no idea what it's doing:

```
if (length(fun.aggregate) > 1) 
        fun.aggregate <- do.call(funstofun, as.list(match.call()[[4]])[-1])
```

Is there a way to pass a premade list of functions as a variable to `cast()`?

Comment: You're using `reshape` here, I think? (Not `reshape2`)

Comment: Aye, you are correct. I was getting confused having both of the packages loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has to use an input argument. The function `cast` automatically passes the values as the first argument to the function. Furthermore, you have to tell R that `summary.fun` is a function using `<- function()`.

```
summary.fun <- function(x) list(mean(x), sd(x), max(x), min(x))
```

Try this function with `cast`.

```
library(reshape)

d <- data.frame(variable="variable",value=rnorm(100))

cast(d, variable ~ ., summary.fun)
```

As @handley pointed out, this does not work with the `cast` function from the `reshape2` package. You should have a look at `dcast` and `acast`.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thanks for the `reshape` answer.